# Autocorrelation plot for only negative values

Tags: r, plot

I would like to do an acf plot in R for only the negative values of a time series. I cannot do this by just subsetting the data for only negative values beforehand, because then the autocorrelation will remove arbitrary number of positive days in between the negative values and be unreasonably high, but rather, I would like to run the autocorrelation on the whole time series and then filter out the results given the first day is negative.

For example, in theory, I could make a data frame with the original series and all of the lagged time series in a data frame, then filter for the negative values in the original series, and then plot the correlations. However, I would like to automate this using the acf plot.

Here is an example of my time series:

```
> dput(exampleSeries)
c(0, 0, -0.000687, -0.004489, -0.005688, 0.000801, 0.005601, 
0.004546, 0.003451, -0.000836, -0.002796, 0.005581, -0.003247, 
-0.002416, 0.00122, 0.005337, -0.000195, -0.004255, -0.003097, 
0.000751, -0.002037, 0.00837, -0.003965, -0.001786, 0.008497, 
0.000693, 0.000824, 0.005681, 0.002274, 0.000773, 0.001141, 0.000652, 
0.001559, -0.006201, 0.000479, -0.002041, 0.002757, -0.000736, 
-2.1e-05, 0.000904, -0.000319, -0.000227, -0.006589, 0.000998, 
0.00171, 0.000271, -0.004121, -0.002788, -9e-04, 0.001639, 0.004245, 
-0.00267, -0.004738, 0.001192, 0.002175, 0.004666, 0.006005, 
0.001218, -0.003188, -0.004363, 0.000462, -0.002241, -0.004806, 
0.000463, 0.000795, -0.005715, 0.004635, -0.004286, -0.008908, 
-0.001044, -0.000842, -0.00445, -0.006094, -0.001846, 0.005013, 
-0.006599, 0.001914, 0.00221, 6.2e-05, -0.001391, 0.004369, -0.005739, 
-0.003467, -0.002103, -0.000882, 0.001483, 0.003074, 0.00165, 
-0.00035, -0.000573, -0.00316, -0.00102, -0.00144, 0.003421, 
0.005436, 0.001994, 0.00619, 0.005319, 7.3e-05, 0.004513)
```

Comment: If you woul give a simple numerical example of how you mean it, it would be easier to help you

Comment: So I tried to give an example, but I'll elaborate further. I have a time series, and I create lagged versions of those time series up to lag.max as columns in a data frame. Then, I subset the data frame so that the first column is negative. I calculate the correlations from column 1 to column 2 as the one day lag, column 1 to column 3 as the 2 day lag, etc. Then, I plot these correlations in the acf plot format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea I ended up writing my own functions and just replacing the values in the R acf object with my own values that are just the correlations. So:

```
genACF <- function(series, my.acf, lag.max = NULL, neg){

    x <- na.fail(as.ts(series))
    x.freq <- frequency(x)
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    if (!is.numeric(x)) 
        stop("'x' must be numeric")
    sampleT <- as.integer(nrow(x))
    nser <- as.integer(ncol(x))

    if (is.null(lag.max)) 
        lag.max <- floor(10 * (log10(sampleT) - log10(nser)))
    lag.max <- as.integer(min(lag.max, sampleT - 1L))
    if (is.na(lag.max) || lag.max < 0) 
        stop("'lag.max' must be at least 0")

    if(neg){

        indices <- which(series < 0)

    }else{

        indices <- which(series > 0)

    }

    series <- scale(series, scale = FALSE)  
    series.zoo <- zoo(series)
    for(i in 0:lag.max){

        lag.series <- lag(series.zoo, k = -i, na.pad = TRUE)
        temp.corr <- cor(series.zoo[indices], lag.series[indices], use = 'complete.obs', method = 'pearson')
        my.acf[i+1] <- temp.corr

    }
    my.acf[1] <- 0
    return(my.acf)

}

plotMyACF <- function(series, main, type = 'correlation', neg = TRUE){

    series.acf <- acf(series, plot = FALSE)
    my.acf <- genACF(series, series.acf$acf, neg = neg)
    series.acf$acf <- my.acf

    plot(series.acf, xlim = c(1, dim(series.acf$acf)[1] - (type == 'correlation')), xaxt = "n", main = main)
    if (dim(series.acf$acf)[1] < 25){

        axis(1, at = 1:(dim(series.acf$acf)[1] - 1))

    }else{

        axis(1)

    }

}
```

And I get something like this:[image]

Comment: You should be aware that computing the autocorrelations of an (effectively) unevenly sampled time series in this way (if I understand correctly what you're doing) might be statistically questionable ... the pattern of occurrence negative values may get confounded with the correlations among the negative values ...

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement your description.

```
correl <- function(x, lag.max = 10){
  library(dplyr)
  m <- matrix(ncol = lag.max, nrow = length(x))
  for(i in 1:lag.max){
    m[,i] <- lag(x, i)
    }
  m <- m[x<0,]
  res <- apply(m, 2, function(y) cor(y, x[x<0], use = "complete.obs"))
  barplot(res)
}

correl(exampleSeries)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I like the way the acf graph looks, though, so I ended up doing something similar but just modifying the acf attribute of an acf plot with my data, and then plotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just write your own function?  Something like:

```
negativeACF <- function(x, num.lags = 10)
{
  n    <- length(x)
  acfs <- sapply(0:num.lags, function(i) cor(x[-i:-1], x[(-n-1+i):-n]))
  names(acfs) <- 0:num.lags
  acfs[acfs < 0]
}

results <- negativeACF(exampleSeries, num.lags=20)
barplot(results)
```

[image: Negative ACFs]